# How to get the list of files associated with a merge request using python-gitlab

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I am intending to make a bot that will make some automated merge request comments based off of the files associated with the merge request.

Is there any easy way to do this?

I stumbled upon a library called python-gitlab that seems helpful but am unsure of how to accomplish this.

It seems like I would have to get a merge request by the merge request id

```py
mr = project.mergerequests.get(mr_id)
```

and then use the merge request to get the source branch 
`how?`
then access the items via the source branch

```py
items = project.repository_tree(path='docs', ref='branch1') # like this?
```

Is there a better way to accomplish creating merge request comments based off of the files associated with the merge request?

Answer (score 2):

You can list the changes in this MR:

```
changes = mr.changes()
```

The 'changes' are the summary of what files are changed and what changes they have. Try print them out. You will be happy about it.

Reference: https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gl_objects/mrs.html